# Problems with BroadcastReceiver and Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a `MainActivity` which do nothing and one class called `BootCompletedIntentReceiver` which `extends BroadcastReciever` and one more class with name `MyServices` which `extends Service`. All I want to do is autorun my app after device turns on which is handled by  `BootCompletedIntentReceiver` and after that it starts a `Service` which shows a toast 8 times. But when i reboot my device nothing happens. I have tried my best to solve this. Can any one help me to find where i am getting stuck

Here is my `BootCompletedIntentReceiver` code:

```
package com.anshuman.myapplication;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class BootCompletedIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(pushIntent);
    }
}
}
```

And here is `MyService` class:

```
package com.anshuman.myapplication;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    int a=2;
    while (a<10) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        a++;
    }

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
 }
}
```

And my androidManifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.anshuman.myapplication">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <receiver android:name=".BootCompletedIntentReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".MyService"/>
</application>
```

Comment: print logs in service and broadcast and remove toast. after that check your app in device

Comment: You must launch the app at least once manually after installation.Otherwise, the BOOT_COMPLETE will not be delivered to your `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Also, your terminology is confusing. A `BroadcastReceiver` is not an `Activity` and a `Service` is also not an `Activity`. I have edited your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Code is working fine problem is that only my xiaomi device is not working with this code.